# Is it possible for JS to continue running after an Android webview's ondestroy runs?

Tags: javascript, android

We're experiencing a weird bug where cookies seem to randomly disappear in Javascript. E.g. during the same session, sometimes users can authenticate and sometimes they can't.

We're running JS within an Android webview. In Android, we have the following code:

```
open class WebViewFragment : Fragment() {
  ...

  override fun onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy()
      clearCookies()
  }

  private fun clearCookies() {
      CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
      CookieManager.getInstance().flush()
  }

  ...
```

Is it possible for JS to continue running after the `onDestroy` runs?